# Condition between elements of A so that A=PAP

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If the $N \times N$ matrix $P$ has $1$ at its antidiagonal and $0$ everywhere else, I want to find the condition between the elements of the matrix $A$ such that $A=PAP$.

I have taken $N=3$. Then we have the $3 \times 3$

$$P=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\ 
0 & 1 & 0\\ 
1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.$$

We want to hold that $A=PAP$, so

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\ 
0 & 1 & 0\\ 
1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\ 
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\ 
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\ 
0 & 1 & 0\\ 
1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}
a_{33} & a_{32} & a_{31}\\ 
a_{23} & a_{22} & a_{21}\\ 
a_{13} & a_{12} & a_{11}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Therefore, it must hold $a_{11}=a_{33}, a_{12}=a_{32}, a_{31}=a_{13}, a_{23}=a_{21}$.

But how can we formally get to the condition for a general $N$ ?

Comment: The general condition will be that $a_{i,j} = a_{n+1-i,n+1-j}$ for all $i$ and $j$.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is as follows. Let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ denote the canonical basis of $\Bbb R^n$. Note that $Pe_i = e_{n+1 - i}$ holds for all $i$.  It follows that 
$$
(PAP)_{ij} = e_i ^T(PAP)e_j = 
(Pe_i)^T A (Pe_j) = e_{n+1-i}^T A e_{n+1-j} = A_{n+1-i,n+1-j}.
$$

Comment: I haven't really understood it. Could you maybe show me also an other approach to understand it better?

Comment: I don't have an alternative explanation.  If you say what it is exactly that you're having trouble understanding, then I could explain the particular step.